# Cypress - Moving login functions from before / beforeEach hooks to a separate file

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, cypress

I recently started writing tests with Cypress and I use a slightly modified version of the code available in one of the official documentation's [recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__jwt/cypress/integration/spec.js):

```
let token: string;

function fetchUser() {
  cy.request('POST', 'https://my-api/', {
    email: Cypress.env("USER_LOGIN"),
    password: Cypress.env("USER_PASSWORD"),
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((res) => {
      token = res.token;
    });
}

function setUser() {
  cy.visit('/projects', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      win.localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({ token }));
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        win.localStorage.setItem(`guidedTour${i}`, 'true');
      }
    },
  });
}
before(fetchUser);
beforeEach(setUser);

it('my test', () => {
// some testing happens here
});
```

It works fine. Now I would like to move `fetchUser` and `setUser` to a separate file to avoid duplicating them in each new test file. When I do that, `fetchUser` takes `token` and sets it to its intended value, but what `setUser` gets is `undefined`. I'm quite the beginner in TypeScript and I have never handled asynchronous functions before, and I'm kinda lost. Here's what I tried:

**authentification.js**

```
export function fetchUser(token: string): string { // Warning: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."
  console.log('fetchUser line 1 ' + token);
  cy.request('POST', 'https://my-api', {
    email: Cypress.env("USER_LOGIN"),
    password: Cypress.env("USER_PASSWORD"),
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((res) => {
      token = res.token;
      return token;
    });
}

export function setUser(token: string) {
  cy.visit('/projects', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      win.localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({ token }));
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        win.localStorage.setItem(`guidedTour${i}`, 'true');
      }
    },
  });
}
```

**main test file**

```
import { fetchUser, setUser } from "../support/authentification";

let token: string;

before(() => {
  token = fetchUser(token);
});
beforeEach(() => {
  setUser(token);
});

it('my test', () => {
// I'd like some testing to still happen here
});
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

This means you don't have a return value from function fetchUser(). The `return token` only alters the subject of the Cypress command chain, but you need to return the `cy.request()` itself to give the function a return value.

The value returned will be `Chainable<string>`, similar to `Promise<string>` - it's value can accessed with `.then(value =>` (but you can't await it).

Also, the request is asynchronous so you can't set the passed-in `token` variable, you must return something that's "then-able", i.e it signals when the asynchronous call is complete.

**authentification.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

export function fetchUser(): Chainable<string> {

  return cy.request('POST', 'https://my-api', {
    email: Cypress.env("USER_LOGIN"),
    password: Cypress.env("USER_PASSWORD"),
  })
  .its('body.token');                // .then() isn't actually needed
                                     // the body.token is the value returned
}
```

**test**

```js
import { fetchUser, setUser } from "../support/authentification";

let token;

before(() => {
  fetchUser().then(val => token = val);    // waits for call to complete
});

beforeEach(() => {
  setUser(token);                          // now token has a value
});

it('my test', () => {
  ...
});
```

---

### Warning - Using Aliases

It's also possible to pass the token by using an alias, but ***Cypress clears aliases between tests***, so this won't work if you have more than one test

```js
before(() => {
  fetchUser().as('token');
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get('@token').then(token => setUser(token));         // fails for 2nd test
});

it('my test', () => {
  ...      
});

it('my 2nd test', () => {
  ...      
});
```

However, an alias also sets a property `this.token` which is ***not cleared between tests***, so this will work

```js
before(() => {
  fetchUser().as('token');
});

beforeEach(function() {                // must use "function()" NOT "() =>" 
  setUser(this.token);                 // succeeds for all tests
});

it('my test', () => {
  ...      
});

it('my 2nd test', () => {
  ...      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question, I would suggest you to move common functions to `support/commands.js` file. Getting value of token in `before` hook, storing it in variable and using it in `beforeEach` hook will not work as `token` value is `undefined` while calling `setUser` function.

You can modify your code little bit:

support/commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('fetchUser', () => {
    return cy.request('POST', 'https://my-api', {
        email: Cypress.env("USER_LOGIN"),
        password: Cypress.env("USER_PASSWORD"),
      })
})


Cypress.Commands.add('setUser', (token) => {
    cy.visit('/projects', {
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
          win.localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({ token }));
          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            win.localStorage.setItem(`guidedTour${i}`, 'true');
          }
        },
      })
})
```

test.spec.js

```js
describe('testing command js', () => {
    beforeEach(() =>{
        cy.fetchUser().then(response => {
            cy.setUser(response.token)
        })
    })

    it('this is test', () => {
        // tests
    })

    it('this is test 2', () => {
        // tests 2
    })
})
```

Updated answer to address the comment. Depending on whether to set user for each tests or once for suite, these methods can be written in `before` and `beforeEach` hook

Please modify the code wherever needed against type checking in Typescript. But this code shall resolve your issue.

Comment: No, it shall not work with a second test.

Comment: In that case, either we need to move fetchUser and setUser either in before hook or beforeEach hook

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom command to run everything

**/cypress/support/authentification.js**

```js
function fetchUser() {
  return cy.request('POST', 'https://my-api', {
    email: Cypress.env("USER_LOGIN"),
    password: Cypress.env("USER_PASSWORD"),
  })
  .its('body.token')   
}

function setUser(token) {
  Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    win.localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({ token }));
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      win.localStorage.setItem(`guidedTour${i}`, 'true');
    }
  })
}

Cypress.Commands.add('fetchAndSetUser', () => {
  fetchUser().then(token => {
    setUser(token)
  })
})
```

**/cypress/support/index.js**

```js
import './authentification.js'
```

**test**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.fetchAndSetUser();
});

beforeEach(() => {                
  cy.visit('/projects')  // onBeforeLoad pre-configured by event 'window:before:load'          
});
```